# Get kernel sources for lubuntu?

Tags: kernel, lubuntu

Answer:
    git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-oneiric.git

works great for ubuntu.

Question:
Does **lubuntu** have such a git server that I can clone from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All versions of Ubuntu user the same kernel, the only variation would be kernel "flavors".

Flavors are variations in the kernel .config

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/Flavours

You can view the various config online

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/

Comment: +1 ty for the clarification - so if I want to build lubuntu, is it just a matter of building the kernel with the right flavor and installing the correct packages?

Comment: Yes. I trust you know what you are wanting if you are asking about building thing ;)